# Custom bindings (knockout.js) to get updated a <select> based upon other <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, knockout.js

I've been using knockout for a couple of months so far but I've managed to get by.

By now, I came across the problem (Let's call it that way) that I cannot get updated the options within a SELECT tag because the ajax methods which retrieves de data from the server are inside a `$(document).ready()` so basically my SELECT tags are filled up with data since the very first moment, but what if wanna change the "options" in the second list based upon what I selected in the first list?

Let me break it down for you, so you see how it goes..

-- An overview of my view [HTML5 + JQM]--

```
<div data-role = "content>
  <label for = "liquorList"> Liquors Categories </label>
  <select data-bind= "options:liqList, 
                      optionsText: 'descitem', 
                      optionsValue: 'iditem', 
                      optionsCaption: 'Choose..', 
                      value: selectedCategory"  name="liquorList"></select>
  <label for = "productList"> Especific Products </label>
  <select data-bind= "options: productList, 
                      optionsText: 'descitem', 
                      optionsValue: 'iditem', 
                      optionsCaption: 'Choose..', 
                      value: selectedProduct"  name="productsList"></select>
</div>
```

-- An overview of my viewModel--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* This is inside a function and retrieves 
       the data to fill the liquorList */  
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : url
        //some code to complete it
    });

    /* Here lies my doubt */
    /* Url is being built up based 
       upon the selectedOption's iditem in the liquorList */
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : url + iditem,
        //some code to complete it
    });
```

I have set on sessionStorage the iditem's value on any change of option (`onchange = "saveIdItem()"`) and it works. Then, I should get from sessionStorage this IDITEM to complete my second url based on that value. BUT I don't even know what event or where to set an option to retrieve this.

For Instance:

If -> the first list has inside "Rum, Vodka, Wine"
and if a choose "Rum" my JSON obtained from the webservice that I'm using should have just data related with Rum like this... "Appleton, Bacardi, Malibu" , which means It'd change depending on what you choose first.

Is there any special event to do that? onblur, onchange all that stuff works to get the value of the 1st list but the 2nd doesn't change automatically. What should I do ? Hope you can help colleagues.

/*****************************************************************************************/
EDITED: 07/06/2014

After Sir @Kristof comments, my code has been turned into this...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    /* This is inside a function and retrieves 
       the data to fill the liquorList */          

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : url
        //some code to complete it

        return liquorServerSideData;
    });

    function appViewModel(){

      this.liquorList = ko.observableArray(liquorServerSideData)
      this.productList = ko.observableArray([]);

    /* Here lies my doubt */
    /* Url is being built up based 
       upon the selectedOption's iditem in the liquorList */

    appViewModel.liquorList.subscribe(function(newValue){
     if(newValue){
      $.ajax({
          type : 'GET',
          url : url + iditem,
          //some code to complete it
          return productServerSideData;
       });
          ko.observableArray(productServerSideData);
       } 

     } // appViewModel ends

     ko.applyBindings( new appViewModel() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly you should be able to subscribe to the selectedCategory observable. 
That way when it's value changes(aka the selection changes) you can react with a json call and change your productList observableArray.

Your code could look something like this :

```
myViewModel.selectedCategory.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : url
        //some code to complete it
    });
});
```

Comment: You thoroughly understood what I wanted to do. Thank you very much Sir @Kristof ! I didn't even know how to apply a suscribe method before, I've been using it quite a lot since I was told though.

The only little thing I couldn't solve was to get an UI automatic-refresh, I don't really know why because I'm able to go through my url and retrieve server-side-data. Right after that, my JSON is built up itself. I can see it on network requests in chrome developer tools.

However, this holy JSON doesn't fulfill the requirements to update my second observable in the same view. Don't you know why?

Comment: Hey rick, having a look at your code for updating the observable would help but if i had to take a guess i'd say that you are using the = operator on the observable instead of using it as a function. If your json returns a new array you can't just = it to the current observable as this will break all the bindings.

Comment: I will have to disagree with you because the operator '=' isn't being used at all. Instead, it's tried to pass as parameters the server-side data retrieved after the AJAX call. Sort of like this... "ko.myObservableExpectedToBeRefreshed(serverSideData);" there has been another ways to pass the data, in order to get an auto-refresh within the DOM  but it seems to be impossible to me.

What could I do?

Comment: Hey rick, you left out the most crucial part inside the //some code to complete it. Your ajax call is assynchronous and you need to use the success or done callback to react to the server response. If you start the ajax call with a $.ajax command and immediatly after set your observable the server didn't respond to your ajax call yet. By using the success callback your code will only run once the request is finished. (you might wanna consider creating a new question for this btw, would give me some more freedom in my answers like code examples etc :) Just pm me the link of your question.